# How to disable profile tab/toolbelt when opening new window in iterm?

Tags: macos, iterm

I have been facing this problem for a quite while now.
Whenever I open new window of iterm, a profile tab/section is automatically opened.

Here is a screenshot.

[image]
It's annoying to close it every time

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to find what it's called.

"Toolbelt"

And it can be disabled[image: Profile preference]

Cheers